# Ruby on Rails dilemma which can't be resolved by me(greenhorn :P)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in Ror and I'm following beginning rails book.
My doubt is that when I run the scaffold command to add the location and excerpt fields;it gives me the following error:

Another migration is already named create_articles: /home/action/blog/db/migrate/20150331131717_create_articles.rb. Use --force to replace this migration file.

When I run the --force command;it gives me   -bash: --force: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You must be running something like:

```
rails generate scaffold Articles
```

By `--force` it means to append it to this command:

```
rails generate scaffold Articles --force
```

Alternatively you could delete the file at:

```
/home/action/blog/db/migrate/20150331131717_create_articles.rb
```

However all of this will be moot if you have already run the migration since your database will be in an incorrect state. Assuming you've already run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

You can roll back this change with:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Comment: thanks Colin..I'll have other doubts too so if u can then plz help me in resolving the doubts :)